# Perl Noting a variable from one file, searching it in another and replacing it

Tags: perl, file, search, replace

This would be my first question.  I want to achieve following by using Perl.
Code should search for parameters mentioned in File1 in File2 and replace the values after ":" in File 2 with value from File1.  Code should replace in-place and do not change/sort the order of parameters in file.

File 1:

```
config1: abc
config2: bcd
config3: efg
```

File 2:

```
config1: cba
config2: sdf
config3: eer
config4: 343
config5: sds
config6: dfd
```

Output --> File2 should look like:

```
config1: abc
config2: bcd
config3: efg
config4: 343
config5: sds
config6: dfd
```

Comment: This sounds like homework (replace in-place and keeping the order of parameters are arbitrary constraints that have zero real life relevancy in a small KVP config file). Can you please show what you tried and what was the difficulty you encountered? StackOverflow is not a "do my work/homework for me" site.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `File::Slurp` to read the file1

  - For each line, use `split` or a regex to separate key from value, and append this key-value pair into a `%file` hash.
- To truly replace in-place, use `-pi` parameters to Perl's command line; (you can try to use `Tie::Hash` but it may be harder).
- You can mimique this by reading file2 using `File::Slurp` into a hash %file2, over-laying `%file1` values on top of `%hash2` values using a loop over keys of `%hash2`, and write the resulting `%hash2` back into the file2 using a `File::Slurp` again after constructing key-valye strings in a correct loop.

If you have difficulties with a specific step, please show what you've done and what the problem is so we can help troubleshoot

Comment: Thanks for responding ... I have created a working codeline using Regex...looping etc....wasn't homework :P...just new to this site.

Answer (score -1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#store params from file1
my (%params);

open(my $FILE1, "< file1.txt") or die $!;
my @arr = <$FILE1>;
foreach(@arr){ 
   #extract key-value pairs \s* = any number of spaces, .* = anything
   #\w+ = any sequence of letters (at least one)
   my ($key, $value) = ($_ =~ /(\w+)\s*:\s*(.*)/);
   $params{$key}=$value; 
}
close $FILE1;

open(my $FILE2, "< file2.txt") or die $!;
my @arr2 = <$FILE2>;
foreach(@arr2){
   my ($key, $value) = ($_ =~ /(\w+)\s*:\s*(.*)/);
   #if the found key did exist in params, then replace the found value, with 
   #the value from file 1 (this may be dangerous if value contains regexp chars, 
   #consider using e.g. \Q...\E
   if (exists $params{$key}) {
       #replace the row in @arr2 inline using direct ref $_
       $_ =~ s/$value/$params{$key}/;
   }
}
close $FILE2
#replace / output the result /here to a different file, not to destroy
open(my $FILE2W, "> file2_adjusted.txt") or die $!;
print $FILE2W @arr2;
close $FILE2W
```